# getting a window name if it has quotes inside C++

Tags: c++, window, title

this is my first post here, so please don't jump on me if I make any mistakes.

Okay, so what I am trying to do is the following:

```
windowtitle = FindWindow(NULL, "blah blah "C:\path\name\here" ");
```

Matter is, I can't get it because as you can see it has quotes inside the quotes.

Any help is welcome, thank you for reading my question, as I said I'm sorry if I made any mistake, it's my first time posting on stackoverflow.

Comment: You must escape the quotes abd backslashes. Try `windowtitle = FindWindow(NULL, "blah blah \"C:\\path\\name\\here\" ");` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the quotes:

```
windowtitle = FindWindow(NULL, "blah blah \"C:\\path\\name\\here\" ");
```

Note you must escape backslashes, too.

See also [list of C++ character escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the quotes with backslashes, like this :`\"`. Then it should work.